# How not to fully collapse a panel of an accodion - have more than 1 open at a time

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, accordion

I need to develop an accordion that have 2 sliders. one contain the header information and the other the child related info. I am using Flex 3 and it should be vertical instead of horizontally. I found a vertical way of doing it.

But the thing is that the header "panel" should not fully collapse when navigating to the child one. So i therefore need to set the min width/height that a specific panel needs to collapse to. if this is not set, the panel should collapse completely.

I had a look on the net on many forums but cant seem to find where/how to go about creating such a component that do not fully collapse a panel.

If anyone can point me in the right direction please

example when Panel 1 is open - the header info

```
P---------------------------P
A---------------------------A
N-------PANEL 1 OPEN--------N
E---------------------------E
L---------------------------L
1---------------------------2
```

example when Panel 1 is open - the header info

```
P----P-----------------------
A----A-----------------------
N----N---PANEL 2 OPEN--------
E----E-----------------------
L----L-----------------------
1----2-----------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'll have to either build your own component from scratch; or extend the existing one to add this functionality.

Comment: any idea what methods should be overridden to do this?

Comment: Nope; I'd start by looking at the Flex Component LifeCycle methods (createChildren(), commitPropeties(), updateDisplayList() in an attempt to figure out how the component works and to determine what should be changed.